# ScrollTop redirecting to home page

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am developing Single page HTML5 web application. For Scrolling Top to the page I am using this code : `$('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 800);`

Its working perfectly in Chrome ,Firefox.

And also the scroll top working In IE home page.But when i take other page in IE and click on scroll button,it will redirecting to the home page.

This particular issue i saw in IE only. Any one please suggest?

I am using Angularjs for my single page application.Please check my code

html code

```
<div data-ng-click="scrollToTop();"><a href="#">Scroll to Top</a></div>
```

AngularJs function

```
$scope.scrollToTop = function(){
    $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 800);
    };
```

Comment: this doesn't have anything to do with your scroll top. Show us the `<a>` element that has the link to go back to the top, and the javascript that handles the click on that link.

Comment: Can you post the full code that you are using?

Comment: I just Updated my code . Can you please have a look

Answer (score 0):

This is because the `href` in the anchor points to `#`.

Try to remove the href

```
<div data-ng-click="scrollToTop();"><a>Scroll to Top</a></div>
```

or, set href to `void`

```
<div data-ng-click="scrollToTop();"><a href="javascript:void(0);">Scroll to Top</a></div>
```